# Как решить проблему с наследованием и XML сериализацией

Tags: c#, xml, serializable

Вот моя функция сериализации:

```
 public static void SaveInXmlFormatt(List<Employee> objGraph, string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(fileName,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream, objGraph);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--> Сохранение объекта в XML-формат");
    }
```

При этом класс `Employee` является базовый для классов `Manager` и `Clerk`.
Моя задача сериализовать `List(Employee)`, который содержит в себе свои классы наследники(`Manager`, `Clerk`). При вызове этой функции выдает исключение `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте у класса `Employee` выставить атрибут `[XmlInclude]`:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Manager)),
 XmlInclude(typeof(Clerk)),
 XmlType]
public class Employee
{
    ...
```

Comment: Можно ещё наоборот, метод сериализации обучить искать наследников рефлексией.

Comment: @Monk: У меня так просто не работало, т. к. конструктор вызывался всё равно у базового типа. Но может быть можно сделать через прокси-тип.